# VBA: How to determine the column with the lowest value of a row?

Tags: vba, excel

This Subroutine checks every row for the lowest value. I want to know in which column this value is as. How do I procede?
Here is what I got so far:

```
Sub LowCol()
    Dim iAnz As Long
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iLevel As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim iPos As Long
    Dim dMin As Double
    iAnz = Worksheets("v1").Cells(6, 3).Value    'amount of columns
    iLevel = Worksheets("b1").Cells(2, 2).Value    'amount of rows

    For i = 0 To iLevel
        Set myrange = Worksheets("b1").Range(Cells(5 + i, 2 + iAnz + 1), Cells(5 + i, 2 + iAnz + iAnz + 1))
        dMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myrange)
        Set rCell = myrange.Find(What:=dMin, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        iPos = CLng(rCell.Column)    'this line is obviously not working. How to fix?
        Worksheets("b1").Cells(5 + i, 2 + iAnz + iAnz + 1).Value = iPos
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `CLng` is a function that converts some value to `Long` data type. I am sure that it is not what you want to do, so what this `iPos = CLng(rCell.Column)` line should do? Or, what `iPos` should be? Column number? Row number?

Comment: Column number - the problem is more that rCell.Column does not work :-/

Comment: I deleted my answer after finding that the Min function ignores blanks.  I also could not recreate the same error that I had without having a complete range of blank values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't as fast as the Min function but it won't make much of a difference unless you are working with large datasets.

```
Function getMinValueColumn(Target As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range, rMin As Range

    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    For Each r In Target
        If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
            If rMin Is Nothing Then Set rMin = r
            If r.Value < rMin.Value Then Set rMin = r
        End If
    Next
    If Not rMin Is Nothing Then getMinValueColumn = rMin.Column
End Function
```

Comment: If r.Value > rMin.Value Then Set rMin = r should be  If r.Value < rMin.Value Then Set rMin = r. This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for getting number of column for `MIN` value. Just use formula with `MATCH`, like:

```
=MATCH(MIN(A1:G1);A1:G1;0)
```

Comment: But if you WANT to do it in VBA: WorksheetFunction.MATCH(WorksheetFunction.MIN("A1:G1"),"A1:G1",0)